# who/where actually work liveness probe in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, kubernetes-cluster

in my kubernetes cluster, http liveness probe always failed with this message

```
Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.233.90.72:8080/health: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

so, `coredns` and `kubernetes-dashboard` (any other using http liveness probe) pods being infinitely restart.

while pod running (between events start and restart), i check the endpoints for the pod with executing command `curl http://10.233.90.72:8080/health` on the `busyboxplus` pod.
this command are working normally, i can see `OK` return. 
but liveness probe still failed. pod is restarting...

in this situation, i want to debug liveness probe, but i don't have any idea who/where actually work liveness probe in kubernetes?
is this pod? or node?

how can i debug liveness probe?
does anyone have same issue..?

please advice for me.

```
kubectl version:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:00:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:00:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

version info:
 OS: Ubuntu 18.04
 Kubernetes: 1.13.3
 Docker: 18.09.2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the DNS already ? using the busybox:1.28 try to execute dns lookup to the pod and see what you get.

```
nslookup pod-ip-in-dash.pod.cluster.local
```

Another thing you can do which you might already did, check in kube-system if coredns pod is running.

Let me know how went,

Comment: because coredns pod being infinitely restart, nslookup failed if coredns pod status is `CrashLoopBackOff`. but nslookup succeded if coredns pod status is `Running` for a while

/ # nslookup busybox1
Server:    10.233.0.3
Address 1: 10.233.0.3 coredns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      busybox1
Address 1: 10.233.123.132 busybox1